# Auto Renewable OR Non Renewable In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

In my iPad application, I'm integrating Amazon SES service to send bulk mail's to respective recipients. App user will have to subscribe for Amazon SES service on monthly basis, to activate it.

**Which will be preferred IAP type(Auto Renewable OR Non Renewable) should I go for, as it is suggested
to use Auto Renewable subscription only for periodic content like Magazine, Newspaper etc.**

Just want to confirm once before implementing functionality & uploading app on app store as, I don't want to get it rejected after uploading.

Thanks

Comment: So the user has to pay amazon *and* you for this service?  Doesn't seem like it would fly as an "in-app" purchase at all...not a renewable one for sure.

Comment: @borrrden: Thanks for reply. A user will only have have to pay only if, he crosses daily free mail sending limit which 2000 mails or data tranfer(as attachment, which is not my app scope). Please refer: http://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/. Can you please explain why IAP, will not fly in my scenario.